# Sticky Header Disappearing Mid Page

Tags: reactjs, header

Here is my header :
https://gist.github.com/eliemada/3b75a3d6cf59440df2910099e8f07cbd
I want to achieve the following :

- A header that smoothly dissapears when i scroll down and reappears when i scroll up
- It can reappear even in the middle of long page

There is multiple issues i am facing :

- Currently i am only disappearing and reappearing  on the top of the page
- And i can still click on the headers buttons (If i understood it is related to the opacity)

If anyone was willing to help that would be wondefull !